# How do I click the button to switch the image of the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make an image slider. It can switch to the next picture by clicking the ">" icon with the mouse, or switch the previous picture by clicking the "<" icon with the mouse. When I want to test the results after the production is completed, it can successfully switch the picture, but I have to click the switch icon twice with the mouse to switch the picture. Originally, my Javascript was placed in the  tag. Later, I tried to move the Javascript to the  tag, hoping that the program could be loaded in advance, but it was still an invalid result.

```js
document.body.onload = showSlides();
function showSlides(){
  slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[0].style.display = "block";  
  slides[1].style.display = "block";
  slides[2].style.display = "block";

}

function showPlusSlides() {
  father = document.getElementById("slideshow-container");
  firstChild = father.firstChild;
  lastChild = father.lastChild;
  father.appendChild(firstChild);
  showSlides();
}

function showReduceSlides() {
  father = document.getElementById("slideshow-container");
  firstChild = father.firstChild;
  lastChild = father.lastChild;
  father.insertBefore(lastChild,firstChild);
  showSlides();
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none; width: 31.3333333333%; float: left;margin: 1%;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 72%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 14%;
  right: 14%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 14%
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 7%;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev {
  left: 7%;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
}


.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: 1} 
  to {opacity: 0.5}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: 1} 
  to {opacity: 0.5}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="./test/css/slider.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container" id="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade" id="11">
  <img src="./test/11.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="1">
  <img src="./test/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="2">
  <img src="./test/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="3">
  <img src="./test/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="4">
  <img src="./test/4.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="5">
  <img src="./test/5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="6">
  <img src="./test/6.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="7">
  <img src="./test/7.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="8">
  <img src="./test/8.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="9">
  <img src="./test/9.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" id="10">
  <img src="./test/10.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>
<a class="prev" id ="prev" onclick="showReduceSlides();">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" id ="next" onclick="showPlusSlides();">&#10095;</a>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./test/js/slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in not sure that it is good idea every time add elements in DOM? you need to build grid ones and move you slide wrapper. Why you don't use slider plugins?

Comment: There is few concepts of sliders: 1. with sliders duplicates, 2. with position absolute and move slides as you want (from left, to top, zoom, rotate..)

Comment: Second concept is simple to write your own, first better use plugins

Comment: @Greg--
Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to use slider plugin.

Comment: try [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) he is have good API